# Is it possible to display a message in php on javascript is disabled?

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display “Enable JavaScript” message only when JavaScript is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334329/display-enable-javascript-message-only-when-javascript-is-disabled)

I have a php document which contains both php and jquery coding. My question though is that is there a way in php where if the brower's javascript is disabled, that it displays a message stating "In order to use this application without any problems, you must have javascript enabled"?

Can the message appear straight away when the user has disabled javascript?

Thanks

Comment: No need for PHP, just use HTML: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/noscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use noscript tag tyo detect if JavaScript not supported.

```
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
```

Comment: Can I stick this no script on a separate php page and then use the include(); to include this php script in any php script?

Comment: yes, you can put this code in a php file and include in all files.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<noscipt>In order to use this application without any problems, you must have javascript enabled</noscript>` Tags

Comment: Good answer, only reason you did not get best answer was because you lost out to Sushil who just beat you in seconds

Answer (score 0):

Anything surrounding by `<noscript>` tags is executed in the case of JavaScript being disabled, so you can simply display a warning from within a `noscript` block.

```
<noscript>In order to use this application without any problems, you must have javascript enabled</noscript>
```

Comment: Good answer, others ahead of you posted their answer and hence why one of them got best answer but you are correct :)