# Consider Browsers with Javascript but CSS disabled - is it reasonable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, usability, noscript

This snippet shows (replacement) content for users without Javascript, similar to the `<noscript>` tag.

```
<SCRIPT> document.write('<style type="text/css">#no_js{display:none;}</style>'); </SCRIPT>
<TAG id="no_js"> Content for users without Javascript </TAG>
<SCRIPT> var x=document.getElementById("no_js");x.parentNode.removeChild(x); </SCRIPT>
```

- Line 1 hides the Content of line 2 with CSS.
- Line 3 additionally removes the content - for Browsers without CSS *but with
  Javascript*.

I wonder whether line 3 is academic and can be left out.

Are there real world users around with no CSS but Javascript ?

*Related posts:*

[Why not noscript tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170484/shouldnt-we-use-noscript-tag)

[Avoid flickering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334329/display-enable-javascript-message-only-when-javascript-is-disabled)

Comment: Why are you not just relying on <script> and <noscript> for this? Doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about user experience.

Comment: @joseeight: noscript tag may fail in special scenarios, see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170484/shouldnt-we-use-noscript-tag)

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to assume anyone would intentionally disabled CSS for normal browsing. Historically, there were reasons people would have javascript disabled, such as security or performance, but that shouldn't be a concern with CSS. **If there's a device using your site that doesn't have CSS, you certainly shouldn't plan on it using javascript.**

Comment: @Liam he said AND javascript enabled. I'll make that more clear.

Comment: `Screen readers for the blind and web-crawlers don't use CSS`. They are both aware of it to some extent, though. For example, `display: none` is recognized by screen readers, and Google notices some of your CSS.

Comment: Sceen readers seem to execute JS, see this survey [link](http://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey3/#javascript) (and, btw, Googlebot surely does.)

Comment: @shful I can't win. If I say one thing, someone will get upset that I didn't say the other. If I don't mention it, someone will comment that I should have ^

Comment: @shful the point is, there's no standard practice involving the question you're asking. I assure you, you don't need to worry about it.